# Tint a UIImage like with a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uibarbuttonitem

Apologies if this is obvious, but why can I not tint an image within a UIImageView like I can tint an image as a UIBarButtonItem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact tint an image in a UIImageView.

Make sure that the `tintColor`-property of your UIImageView is set to the color your want, and then make sure that your UIImage has the correct rendering mode. `UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic` should work - but to force it to tint you can use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`.

You can change the rendering mode of an existing image like this:

```
UIImage *myImage = ...
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
myImageView.image = myImage;
```

Please refer to the [Apple Documentation on template images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW1) for more detailed information.

Comment: In Xcode 6 and iOS 8, Apple added the ability to specify an image in an asset catalog as being a template image, so you don’t have to do anything special in code other than `+[UIImage imageNamed:]`.